# R: How to write CRS information correctly to NetCDF?

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

As the title says, I'm struggling with writing the CRS of a multi layer raster stack to a NetCDF file using a [custom package](https://greenbrown.r-forge.r-project.org/man/WriteNCDF.html). This package uses the functions of the ncdf4-package. But the written .nc file doesn't have the CRS information which the source raster had. I've already read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201112/set-projection-netcdf-with-r-ncdf4-package) thread and I tried to replicate it, tweaking the WriteNCDF function from above. I tried it with:

```
ncatt_put(nc, var.name, 'proj4', crs(data), 'double')
```

with `nc`as the to be written ncdf file and `data` as the rasterlayer.
This results in the following error:

> Error in ncatt_put_inner(idobj$group_id, idobj$id, attname, attval, prec = prec,  :
> ncatt_put: error, passed an attribute with a storage mode not handled.  Att name: proj4 Att value: +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs Storage mode passed: S4 .  Handled types: integer double character

Afterwards I tried it with:

```
ncatt_put(nc, var.name, 'proj4', crs(data, asText = T), 'text')
```

This doesn't produce an error but when I open the written .nc file with `raster::brick()`, the CRS isn't found.
So how do I put CRS information correctly into a NetCDF file?

Minimal code to run:

```
library('ncdf4')
library('raster')
source('WriteNCDF.R')


r <- raster(crs="+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84", xmn=0, xmx=10, ymn=0, ymx=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- stack(r, r/2)
x <- writeRaster(s, filename="test.nc")
crs(x)

z <- WriteNCDF(data.l = list(s$layer.1, s$layer.2), 
               var.name = c('layer1', 'layer2'), 
               var.unit = c('unit', 'unit'),
               file = 'test2.nc',
               utm = T)
zz <- brick('test2.nc', varname = 'layer1')
crs(zz)
```

The tweaked `WriteNCDF.R` can be found [here](https://cloudstore.zih.tu-dresden.de/index.php/s/si4EZsXAd5GC5F6).

Comment: That last link goes to a 54.6Mb NetCDF file.... Did you mean to point to some R code?

Comment: Why is using `writeRaster(s, filename="test.nc")` not doing what you want? It saves the data and the CRS. What is `WriteNCDF` supposed to do extra?

Comment: @Spacedman I fixed the link. The problem I have with `writeRaster()` is on one hand the limitation of meta-data you can write to the .nc files and on the other hand, how to write a multi-layer raster stack where each layer has the same time dimension. If you write a multi-layer raster stack (e.g. all Sentinel-2 bands) with `writeRaster()` ncdf option, every band is another data point on the z-axis (time dimension).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `test.nc` file written via `raster::writeRaster` uses the CF-1.4 metadata convention for spatial data. If you look at it with `ncdump` you can see that the CRS is stored as a `proj4` attribute of an integer variable called `crs`:

```
variables:
    int crs ;
        crs:proj4 = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" ;
```

The `crs` variable itself seems to have a missing value - but that's okay, the text is in the attribute above:

```
data:

 crs = _ ;

 easting = 0.0138888888888889, 0.0416666666666667, 0.0694444444444444, 
    0.0972222222222222, 0.125, 0.152777777777778, 0.180555555555556,
```

The `WriteNCDF` function stores the CRS as an attribute of the layer data. `ncdump` shows this:

```
    float layer1(time, north, east) ;
            layer1:units = "unit" ;
            layer1:_FillValue = -9999.f ;
            layer1:scale_factor = 1. ;
            layer1:add_offset = 0. ;
            layer1:proj4 = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" ;
```

Now I don't think that conforms to the CF-1.4 metadata spec so I doubt any geospatial software is going to read that back when you read the file.

You can either make it conform to the CF-1.4 metadata spec by writing the correct attributes etc (but that might not be possible if your data fundamentally won't fit the spec), or write a counterpart `ReadNCDF` function that uses the `ncdf4` package functions to read these attributes directly after reading the raster grid with `raster` - for example:

```
> s2 = nc_open("test2.nc")
> ncatt_get(s2, "layer1","proj4")$value
[1] "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

which opens the NetCDF file then gets the "proj4" attribute from variable "layer1".